# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icu'

Tags: python-3.x

Есть код:

```
from polyglot.text import Text as T
text = T("это очень плохо. А это намного лучше, даже хорошо!")
print(text.polarity)

for s in text.sentences:
    print(s, s.polarity)


for w in text.words:
   print("{:<16}{:>2}".format(w, w.polarity))
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/perforce/Social/text2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from polyglot.text import Text as T
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\text.py", line 9, in <module>
    from polyglot.detect import Detector, Language
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\detect\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import Detector, Language
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\polyglot\detect\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from icu import Locale
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icu'
```

Я не очень понимаю при чем тут модуль icu. И зачем он нужен. Но при попытке установить pyicu через `pip install pyicu`. Появляется ошибка:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2piri80w\pyicu
```

Comment: [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/) — это библиотека для работы с unicode'ом. Очевидно, она является зависимостью `polyglot`'а и, по видимому, не установлена...

Comment: значит, нужно установить pyicu?

Comment: скорей всего — да.